# Group Policy Preventing Adobe Save As PDF for Excel Documents

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, adobe-acrobat

## Summary

- A user tries to `Save as PDF` but results in a "Not Responding" excel document.
- User needs the `Save as PDF` option to save multiple worksheets from a workbook.
- The Excel Document uses Macros and Protected Sheets, but this doesn't impact other documents in the same directory
- these excel documents are hosted in the same network drive as working `Save as PDF` excel documents

## Steps So Far

1. Tested Save as PDF for user: failure
2. Tested Save as PDF for my account, on a new computer (TEST-PC): success
3. 24hours passed, tested Save as PDF function for TEST-PC: failure
4. disabled Macros: No success
5. unlocked worksheet: No success

failure in this case is the `Save as PDF` function getting to the `do you want to save as PDF? Yes/No` message, Where clicking `Yes` causes Excel to not respond.

## Current Theory

I think this may be a group policy issue, given the gap where I was able to print successfully from the TEST-PC, but when I waited (which I assume would allow Group Policy to apply) the culprit documents would not `Save as PDF`

Is there something in Group Policy that could cause this type of issue?
Are there any other items I could check?

Comment: Save as PDF started working when running Excel in Safe mode. I'm thinking it's a Macro causing the issue at this point. Unclear if it is permissions based or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing Office 2010 with Office 2019 seemed to resolve this issue.

1. remove Office 2010
2. install Office 2019
3. verify that Save As PDF works and allows Worksheets to be selected